# UPDATE using select statement and inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
UPDATE TABLE1 set TABLE1.col1 = TABLE2.col1
FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON COL2 = TABLE2.COL2
WHERE TABLE1.COL3 = TABLE3.COL3
```

Will the above query work if the `JOIN` returns multiple rows per condition? I am unable to update it, inspite of being able individually to `Join` `Table3` and `Table2`.

Please help. I hope the information is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to choose only 1 row from Table2 - sql server will choose the any suitable row from Table2 instead.

Comment: @onedaywhen yes, you just right. I've checked it and corrected the answer

Comment: @onedaywhen So doctrinal and pedant! 8-) Corrected. I tested with heap and clustered key join - in clust it chooses the last value, in heap - arbitrary

Comment: It's undefined in both cases. What if you get a hash join?

Comment: @onedaywhen No I'm really not. It was the first word i thought when seen it. Of course in my native language 8-)

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, I already realized, that had a wrong approach when resized the particular, but repeatable result to "the behavior"

Answer (score 3):

If there are multiple rows, then an arbitrary row will be used for the update. No error will be given. 
You can make it mandatory that one row is returned by the join by [changing the UPDATE to a MERGE](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2008/03/lets-deprecate-update-from/)

Answer (score 2):

As you are on SQL Server 2005 `MERGE` is not available to you.

To get a deterministic result you need a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET    TABLE1.col1 = ISNULL((SELECT TOP (1) TABLE2.col1
                             FROM   TABLE2
                                    INNER JOIN TABLE3
                                      ON TABLE3.COL2 = TABLE2.COL2
                             WHERE  TABLE1.COL3 = TABLE3.COL3
                             ORDER  BY TABLE2.col1), TABLE1.col1)
```